# How to convert float to Decimal while using eval?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming so I thought I'd ask here for help.
So when I use:

```
eval('12.5 + 3.2'),
```

it converts 12.5 and 3.2 into floats.
But I want them to be converted into the Decimal datatype.

I can use:

```
from decimal import Decimal
eval(Decimal(12.5) + Decimal(3.2))
```

But I can't do that in my program as I'm accepting user input.

I've found a solution but it uses regular expressions, which I'm not familiar with right now (and I can't find it again for some reason).

It would be great if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're aware that user input and `eval` is a cocktail for disaster in anything other than a toy program?

Comment: Yeah. I'm writing this to practice so I'm the only one using this program.

Comment: So just do `a = eval("Decimal(12.5) + Decimal(3.2)")`

Comment: @anky_91 That converts it to a float first and then converts it to a Decimal. I'm pretty sure that doesn't give you the same output as eval("Decimal(12.5) + Decimal(3.2)").

Comment: @roganjosh I could do that. But I actually wanted to know if there was anyway to make it so that it actually converts it to a Decimal. I'm just trying out new things as I learn and wanted to know if there was a way to do it.

Comment: It already does?

Comment: But I want to convert '12.5' to a Decimal instead of a float without using Decimal('12.5'), I guess. Maybe I'm phrasing my question wrong?

Comment: The question makes sense to me. Given an arbitrary string representing an arithmetic expression, evaluate it as if each float literal was actually a decimal object. You can't just add "Decimal(" to the string manually, because the string is unknown until runtime when the user supplies it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE: apparently the official docs has a recipe that does exactly what you're looking for. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#examples:

```
from tokenize import tokenize, untokenize, NUMBER, STRING, NAME, OP
from io import BytesIO

def decistmt(s):
    """Substitute Decimals for floats in a string of statements.

    >>> from decimal import Decimal
    >>> s = 'print(+21.3e-5*-.1234/81.7)'
    >>> decistmt(s)
    "print (+Decimal ('21.3e-5')*-Decimal ('.1234')/Decimal ('81.7'))"

    The format of the exponent is inherited from the platform C library.
    Known cases are "e-007" (Windows) and "e-07" (not Windows).  Since
    we're only showing 12 digits, and the 13th isn't close to 5, the
    rest of the output should be platform-independent.

    >>> exec(s)  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    -3.21716034272e-0...7

    Output from calculations with Decimal should be identical across all
    platforms.

    >>> exec(decistmt(s))
    -3.217160342717258261933904529E-7
    """
    result = []
    g = tokenize(BytesIO(s.encode('utf-8')).readline)  # tokenize the string
    for toknum, tokval, _, _, _ in g:
        if toknum == NUMBER and '.' in tokval:  # replace NUMBER tokens
            result.extend([
                (NAME, 'Decimal'),
                (OP, '('),
                (STRING, repr(tokval)),
                (OP, ')')
            ])
        else:
            result.append((toknum, tokval))
    return untokenize(result).decode('utf-8')
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
from decimal import Decimal
s = "12.5 + 3.2 + 1.0000000000000001 + (1.0 if 2.0 else 3.0)"
s = decistmt(s)
print(s)
print(eval(s))
```

Result:

```
Decimal ('12.5')+Decimal ('3.2')+Decimal ('1.0000000000000001')+(Decimal ('1.0')if Decimal ('2.0')else Decimal ('3.0'))
17.7000000000000001
```

Feel free to skip the rest of this answer, which is now only of interest to historians of half-correct solutions.

---

As far as I know, there's no easy way to "hook into" eval in order to change how it interprets float objects.

But if we use the `ast` module to convert your string into an abstract syntax tree before `eval`ing it, then we can manipulate the tree to replace the floats with Decimal calls.

```
import ast
from decimal import Decimal

def construct_decimal_node(value):
    return ast.Call(
        func = ast.Name(id="Decimal", ctx=ast.Load()),
        args = [value],
        keywords = []
    )
    return expr

class FloatLiteralReplacer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Num(self, node):
        return construct_decimal_node(node)

s = '12.5 + 3.2'
node = ast.parse(s, mode="eval")
node = FloatLiteralReplacer().visit(node)
ast.fix_missing_locations(node) #add diagnostic information to the nodes we created
code = compile(node, filename="", mode="eval")
result = eval(code)
print("The type of the result of this expression is:", type(result))
print("The result of this expression is:", result)
```

Result:

```
The type of the result of this expression is: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
The result of this expression is: 15.70000000000000017763568394
```

As you can see, the result is identical to what you would have gotten if you had calculated `Decimal(12.5) + Decimal(3.2)` directly.

---

But perhaps you're thinking "Why isn't the result 15.7?". This is because `Decimal(3.2)` is not exactly identical to 3.2. It's actually equal to `3.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125`. This is a hazard when it comes to initializing decimals using float objects -- the inaccuracy is already present. Better to use strings to create decimals, e.g. `Decimal("3.2")`.

Maybe you're now thinking "Ok, so how do I turn `12.5 + 3.2` into `Decimal("12.5") + Decimal("3.2")`?". The quickest approach would be to modify `construct_decimal_node` so the Call's args is an ast.Str rather than an ast.Num:

```
import ast
from decimal import Decimal

def construct_decimal_node(value):
    return ast.Call(
        func = ast.Name(id="Decimal", ctx=ast.Load()),
        args = [ast.Str(str(value.n))],
        keywords = []
    )
    return expr

class FloatLiteralReplacer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Num(self, node):
        return construct_decimal_node(node)

s = '12.5 + 3.2'
node = ast.parse(s, mode="eval")
node = FloatLiteralReplacer().visit(node)
ast.fix_missing_locations(node) #add diagnostic information to the nodes we created
code = compile(node, filename="", mode="eval")
result = eval(code)
print("The type of the result of this expression is:", type(result))
print("The result of this expression is:", result)
```

Result:

```
The type of the result of this expression is: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
The result of this expression is: 15.7
```

But take care: while I expect this approach to return good results most of the time, there is a corner case where it returns surprising results. In particular, when the expression contains a float `f` such that `float(str(f)) != f`. In other words, when the printed representation of the float lacks the precision necessary to represent the float exactly.

For example, if you changed `s` in the above code to `"1.0000000000000001 + 0"`, the result would be `1.0`. This is incorrect, since the result of `Decimal("1.0000000000000001") + Decimal("0")` is `1.0000000000000001`.

I'm not sure how you could prevent this problem... By the time `ast.parse` has finished executing, the float literal has already been converted into a float object, and there's no obvious way to retrieve the string that was used to create it. Perhaps you could extract it from the expression string, but you'd basically have to reinvent Python's parser to do that.

Comment: You've been a great help! Thanks for the detailed explanations!

Comment: Could you tell me what the three underscores do in "for toknum, tokval, _, _, _ in g:"? I read that it can be used as a placeholder for an unused variable but I don't see why it should be used here.

Comment: Yes, those underscores represent unused variables. When `g` is iterated over, it yields tuples that contain five elements each. In order to unpack those elements into individual variables, the for loop must provide five names. If you try to provide only two variable names, the code will crash with `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I slightly adapted the code and removed the "and '.' in tokval", because non floats (int) should also be replaced in a formula.